# ACM check Failed while download file from BIM#60 using Forge app

Tags: autodesk-forge

When i try to download a file from BIM360 using Forge application, I am getting the following error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8t3jj.png)

Data Management and Assets services are enabled in BIM360. I have the admin permission for project specified.

Comment: AUTH-012 means "The Authorization header is missing or invalid" ([Forge Docs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling)). Can you share more information about the request and confirm you're including the the token?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but managed to solve it by realizing that the bucketId (wip.dm.prod) that I used to download the file was not constant but did actually depend on the storage on ACC/BIM360 (wip.dm.prod, or wip.dm.emea.2, etc.).

Retrieving the exact bucketId for the given file to download (accessible from the `href` variable in the `storage` metadata) did the trick.

Hope it can help someone.